# Android Html.fromHtml() does not work correctly on nested text style

Tags: android, html

I want to display the HTML

```
"<html><body><font color=\"black\">
In the name of <font color=\"blue\"><b> God</b></font>
the compassionate, the merciful</font></body><html>"
```

in a TextView. So I have used `Html.fromHtml()`, but output is different compared with browsers.

The difference is that the word "God" does not appear in blue color in the TextView.

Code:

```
textView.setText("<html><body><font color=\"black\">
  In the name of <font color=\"blue\"><b> God</b></font>
  the compassionate, the merciful</font></body><html>");
```

Comment: Also if you have any screen shots of the differences with browsers, please share

Comment: also screenshots of mobile and browser outputs if possible.

Comment: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-quick-tip-formatting-text-with-html-fromhtml/

Comment: font has been depracted. Use span

Answer (score 0):

[Html.fromHtml(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) does not support all HTML tags

List of allowed HTML tags:

- br
- p
- div
- em
- b
- strong
- i
- dfn
- big
- small
- font
- blockquote
- tt
- a
- sup
- sub

Comment: Then, Question not about which tags are supported or not.

Comment: this blows. HTML.fromHTML() comprehends <span> and <span style="color: #000000;">, but it can't comprehend nested spans, so I must write only non-nested spans that are not DRY

Answer (score 0):

Try out like this:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body>In the name of<font color=blue><b> God </b></font>the compassionate, the merciful</body><html>"));
```

> Note: **Black** is default color so you dont have to use `<font>` tag for black color.

if you want to use then complete tags right way like (for example for `GRAY` and `BLUE`):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body><font color=gray>In the name of </font><font color=blue><b> God </b></font><font color=gray>the compassionate, the merciful</font></body><html>"));
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't answer the question. Seems like `fromHtml` has a bug and unable to handle nested colors properly and there is no  solution for it (usually you get HTML code from external source and cannot modify it) except either custom handler or pre-processing the code

Comment: There is a small limitation in the Android Html library which means that all font open tags must have a corresponding closing tag </font>. This is not a requirement of regular html because its implied that a new tag will implicitly terminate the preceding font tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue was fixed in `HtmlCompat`. So try using this instead of old deprecated `Html`:

```java
import androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat;

....

HtmlCompat.fromHtml(stringVar, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```